IntelliJ - custom themes for light and dark system theme?
In IntelliJ's PyCharm 2024, when I set Theme -> Sync with OS, it switches from my (astonishingly beautiful) custom theme to the (dare I say, bland) default Light theme.
Is there a way to specify my own themes for light and dark system modes?

In Settings, "Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance" go to "Gear" near "Sync with OS", and select the preferred theme and Editor color scheme for both Dark and Light system modes separately.
Available only in the 2023.3+ version; update if you don't see the gear.


This solution works only for the predefined pycharm themes, however it does not allow to switch to a custom theme. I see this behavior on the 2024.1.2RC

I created a custom theme plugin, and I was able to see it in this list. If you don't see your theme plugin, the author did not implement it correctly. Please report the issue to the plugin author.

I do see themes in the list but pycharm don't switch to any of them. I click on any of custom theme, pycharm shows a check mark, but it does not change the schema. If I reopen this dialog pycharm shows the previously selected schema (one from the default schemas provided by pycharm).  I tried these actions with at least 4 different authors, and all of them have the same problem (material, atom, etc..). So I'm afraid the problem goes from the pycharm.
